# Error calling R script from octave on HPC cluster

Tags: r, ssh, cluster-computing, octave, hpc

I have one `octave` script which calls a `R` script to do some calculation on a HPC cluster. The calculation procedure is as follow:

1. Submit job on the cluster to get computation node assigned then distribute calculation to each CPUs in that node. Part of the shell script looks like this

   ```
   count=0

   HOSTLIST=

   for host in `cat $PBS_NODEFILE`

     do

       HOSTLIST[$count]=$host

       count=$(($count+1))

   done

   ...
   ...
   ...

   mkdir case_$count

   cd case_$count

   export workdir=`pwd`

   remotehost=${HOSTLIST[$pcount]}

   ssh -n $remotehost "cd $workdir; export PATH=$PATH:$workdir; octave $MFILE > /dev/null" &
   ```
2. For the sake of simplicity, the sample `$MFILE` content is

   ```
   printf("Calling R script from Octave \n");

   system('./hello_world.R');
   ```
3. The `hello_world.R`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/Rscript
   print("Hello World!")
   ```
4. Error encountered when run

   ```
   sh: ./hellow_world.R: /usr/bin/Rscript: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
   ```
5. Some of my environment variables (just in case)

   ```
   $ echo $PATH

   /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/maui/bin:/opt/torque/bin:/opt/torque/sbin:/opt/pvfs2/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin

   $ which Rscript 

   /usr/bin/Rscript

   $ which R

   /usr/bin/R
   ```

If I run the `$MFILE` from command line, it worked ok and printed the desired output just fine. I have tried many solutions I could find on the net to no avail

Anybody knows what went wrong? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: When you say you have run the $MFILE from the command line, is that on the cluster?  Can you test it on an interactive node? It seems like it is having a hard time either finding the command for Rscript or your hellow_world.R file, either of which are working directory issues.

Comment: Thanks @darwin! Yes the $MFILE run ok from the command line on the cluster itself but having problem running on separated CPUs of the assigned computational node. To be honest, I'm pretty novice when it comes to HPC/cluster. Could you tell me how can I test it on interactive nodes? I'll look further into this

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem. I ended up converting my R code to octave to get the program running. Thank you though. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was R was loaded on login node but wasn't loaded on the compute node. So in the job submission script, there must be a line to load `R` before doing any calculation. For example:

```
    module load r/3.4.3
```

See more [here](https://hpcf.umbc.edu/other-packages/how-to-run-r-programs-on-maya/#heading_toc_j_0) and [here](https://ulhpc-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/R/#parallel-r)